# choose the layer order for geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to order the layers of `geom_segment` in my `ggplot` (as in when they overlap, choose which segment is shown and which is covered).

Specifically, I would like to order them in factor level. Unfortunately, it seems to always order them in reverse alphabetical order. Is there any way to change the default ordering?

**Example:**

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B'),
  XStart = c(0,   5),
  XEnd   = c(10,  5),
  YStart = c(0,   0),
  YEnd   = c(10,  10)
)

# Order group A first - I want A to be on top
df$Group <- factor(df$Group, levels = c('A', 'B'), ordered = T)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group))

# order group B first - I want B to be on top
df$Group <- factor(df$Group, levels = rev(c('A', 'B')), ordered = T)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group))
```

The output for both of these has A on the bottom

**Output:**

[image]

Does anyone know how to force A to be shown over B?

Comment: Side note - all factors have an order for their levels. You don't need to specify `ordered = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where the order of rows in your data matters to `ggplot`. The segments are plotted in row order, so if you want A to be on top, you need to order your data frame so the A rows are last.

```
# A on bottom
ggplot(data = df[order(df$Group), ]) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group))

# A on top
ggplot(data = df[order(df$Group, decreasing = TRUE), ]) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group))
```

Comment: I never new the row order could be important! Thanks this is a nice simple solution

Comment: It *almost* never is in ggplot. People who learn base graphics first often assume it is---there's plenty of other question where people want to reorder a legend, or an axis, by changing row order---but that doesn't work in ggplot. This is the only case I know of where it still matters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps hacky, but the geom layers are imposed in the order you specify them, so you can specify to first show the "B" data and then the "A" data like so:

```
ggplot() +
# Impose the B line first
  geom_segment(data = dplyr::filter(df, Group == "B"), 
               aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group)) +
# Impose the A line second
    geom_segment(data = dplyr::filter(df, Group == "A"), 
               aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group))
```

[image]

EDIT: If you have a long list of layers to put in, you can capture them in a function, and then iterate through the groups using `purrr::map`. First create the function:

```
geom_this <- function(x) {
  geom_segment(data = dplyr::filter(df, Group == x), 
               aes(x = XStart, xend = XEnd, 
                   y = YStart, yend = YEnd, 
                   colour = Group,
                   size = Group))
}
```

And then iterate it:

```
ggplot() + purrr::map(rev(levels(df$Group)), geom_this)
```

That line of code creates the same plot as above.

Comment: oof, that is hacky... I guess it'll work, but in my real data I have a bunch more layers so was hoping not to have t do this :P

Comment: yeah, that works a little better. Thanks. Hopefully this is just a but they sort out for future releases